# Is there way to specify container runtime for container inside kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to have a container inside a pod, that uses some docker runtime (we can specify it using `--runtime` flag in pure docker).

In my case, I want to use `nvidia-docker2` runtime (https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) for using GPU inside my containers in Kubernetes cluster.

**Answer:** Specify default runtime in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` like that:

```
"default-runtime": "nvidia",
"runtimes": {
    "nvidia": {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use "`nvidia-docker` runtime (https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) for using GPU inside your containers in Kubernetes cluster", then take a look into the official docs provided by keubernetes themselves:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/device-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use kubernetes device plugin which creates daemonset and allows you to expose the GPU metrics on each node.

https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin